# Explanation of solution: integral calculation with Dirac $\delta$ ( Fourier transform)

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, dirac-delta

Can someone explain to me this solution :

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta (\tau -\frac{1}{4}t)e^{-j2\pi f_dt}dt=e^{-j2\pi f_d4\tau }$$

When I have solved, I got $e^{-j2\pi f_d4t }$

But the answer is: $e^{-j2\pi f_d4\tau }$

Where I have made the mistake?

Comment: Strange : you could pull $\delta(...)$ out of the integral... There must be a problem in the naming of your variables...

Comment: I can't see that the integral makes sense as written. I would expect $\delta (t - \frac{1}{4})$ in your integral but then the result would be $e^{-f2\pi f_d \frac{1}{4}}$.

Comment: Just a thought, should it be $\delta (\tau - \frac{t}{4})$?

Comment: @Paul oh..sorry i made a mistake

Comment: Might be best to leave the question in its original form as the comments now make no sense. I presume you see where the $4\tau$ comes from now?

Comment: You are integrating over $dt$. Therefore the result cannot contain the variable $t$

Answer (score 0):

If we want linear changes of variables to be the same for regular and for singular functionals, we get
$$\int \delta {\left( \tau - \frac t 4 \right)} e^{-2 \pi j t f_d} dt =
4 \int \delta {\left( \tau - u \right)} e^{-8 \pi j u f_d} du =
4 e^{-8 \pi j \tau f_d }.$$
Also note that this is just a notation (say, for the Fourier transform), because typically $e^{j t}$ is not a test function to which we can directly apply the functional $\delta$.

Comment: Inasmuch as the Dirac Delta has compact support $\{0\}$ as a distribution ([See This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_%28mathematics%29#Support_of_a_distribution)), then the functional $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x) e^{ix}\,dx=1$ even though $e^{ix}$ is not in the space of Schwartz functions.

Comment: But if you agree that $e^{i x}$ is not in the space of test functions (otherwise we get a space of functionals which is too narrow), you haven't defined $(\delta(x), e^{i x})$ yet. First you have to define a second function space to include $e^{i x}$ (you didn't say how), and secondly, you get a piecemeal system where some functionals can be applied to functions from the first space and some to functions from the second space. I believe these are the reasons why it's not usually done this way.

Comment: So, are you suggesting that the Fourier Transform of the Dirac Delta is not $1$?  And are you suggesting that the FT of $1$ is not the Dirac Delta?

Comment: Clearly for a regularization of the Dirac Delta, $\delta_n(x)$, such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta_n(x)\phi(x)\,dx=\phi(0)$$for all suitable test functions, we also have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta_n(x-x_0)e^{ix}\,dx= e^{ix_0}$$The key is that $\delta(x)\sim\lim_{n\to\infty}\delta_n(x)$ has support on $\{0\}$.  The behavior of $\phi(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is not relevant provided that $\phi$ is continuous at $0$ or has a removable discontinuity at $0$.

Comment: No, it just means that we have to define the Fourier transform differently. The action of $\mathcal F[f]$ on $\phi$ is defined as $(\mathcal F[f], \phi) = (f, \mathcal F[\phi])$. A regularization usually means a functional constructed from an ordinary function, I believe here you rather mean a sequence of functionals converging to $\delta$. But we're back to the same issue of defining the action of $\delta_n$ on $e^{i x}$, which is not a test function.

Comment: Well, if we have a sequence of functionals that converge to $\delta$, then we can certainly apply those to $f=e^{ix}$ with $\langle \delta_n,f\rangle $.  Then, $\langle \delta,f\rangle\equiv \lim_{n\to \infty}\langle \delta_n,f\rangle$.

Comment: But, if that isn't rigorous enough, let $\phi$ be a Schwartz function and let $\mathscr{F}\{\delta\}$ be the Fourier Transform of $\delta$ as defined as a distribution.  Inasmuch as $\langle \mathscr{F}\{\delta\}, \phi \rangle =\langle \delta ,\mathscr{F}\{\phi\}\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\,dx$, then clearly we have $\mathscr{F}\{\delta\}=1$ in distribution.  Does that suffice?  Aside, I do enjoy and appreciate your elucidating things nicely.

Comment: We cannot apply those to $f$. A functional $\delta_n$ takes an ordinary function from a certain function space and returns a complex number. If $f$ is not in that space, $\langle \delta_n, f \rangle$ is an undefined object. This may be a notation for the Fourier transform (which is mentioned in the answer), but not for the action of $\delta$ on $e^{i x}$.

Comment: I presume that this last comment was not in response to my last comment, but rather to my penultimate one(s).

Comment: To be clear, you are distinguishing between the FT of $\delta$ and the functional $\langle \delta, e^{ix}\rangle$.  Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct. $\mathcal F[\delta] = 1$ is certainly true, but, formally from the definition of linear functionals, $\langle \delta, e^{i x} \rangle$ (I wouldn't call it a functional, it's the result of applying the functional to the function) is undefined. I believe if you want to give an explanation of why applying certain functionals to $e^{i x}$ in this illegitimate way can give correct results, you should rather take a sequence of test functions approximating $e^{i x}$, not a sequence of functionals. But this is not straightforward.

Comment: How does $e^{ix}e^{-\epsilon x^2}$ work?

Comment: Actually, it may be even less straightforward than I thought. We are going on a tangent here, but the convergence on the space of functions of rapid decay is defined in such a way as to make the space closed.